# How to print selected string in select option drop down in csharp cshtml ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, razor

I new in ASP.NET.
I try to print selected string in select option drop down but Compilation error.

> Compilation Error    Description: An error occurred during the
> compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
> review the following specific error details and modify your source
> code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment,
> decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a
> statement

Here is my cshtml code.

```
@{ string FromAMPM = "AM";  }

<select id="FromAMPM" name="FromAMPM" class="form-control js-select">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="AM" @if (FromAMPM == "AM") { "selected"; } else { ""; }>AM</option>
<option value="PM" @if (FromAMPM == "PM") { "selected"; } else { ""; }>PM</option>
</select>
```

What wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ternary conditional operator` in your case:

```
@{ string FromAMPM = "AM";  }

<select id="FromAMPM" name="FromAMPM" class="form-control js-select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="AM" @(FromAMPM == "AM" ? "selected='selected'" : "")>AM<</option>
  <option value="PM" @(FromAMPM == "PM" ? "selected='selected'" : "")>PM<</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be separate logic and html

```
 @{
    var FromAMPM = "PM";
    
    var items = new List<SelectListItem>
    {  
        new SelectListItem { Value= "",   Text="Select" },
        new SelectListItem { Value= "AM",  Text="AM" },
        new SelectListItem { Value="PM",   Text="PM"}
    };
}
```

you don't neeed selected code, it will automatically select asp-for value

```
<select id="fromAMPM" asp-for="@FromAMPM" class="form-control js-select" asp-items="@items"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Beside this way have any better and shorter ways?